# The Fitness function must return one scalar

Tags: matlab, genetic-algorithm

I have an error on Matlab saying that my Fitness-function (Genetic Algorithm) should return one scalar. The goal is to compute the optimal coefficient x(1) x(2) and x(3):

```
function score= Fitness_fct(x,L,C,COV,expected_score) 
   %L,C,COV and expected_score are vector of size 22 by 1
   %x is the population (coefficients) that the GA uses

   score=sqrt(power(((power(L,x(1)) + power(C,x(2))+power(COV,x(3)))- 
      expected_value),2));
end

 FitnessFunction =@(x) Fitness_fct(x,L ,C,COV, expected_score );
 [x,fval] = ga(FitnessFunction,4);
 % here x will be the optimized coefficients and fval will be the   
   value obtained by the optimized coefficients
```

After getting the optimized coefficients (x(1), x(2),x(3)), i will compute the final score that i want it to be close to the vector "Expected_value" :

```
for i=1:22
final_score(i)= ((power(L,x(1)) + power(C,x(2))+power(COV,x(3));
end
```

Am i wrong on something in the approach ?

Comment: Your fitness function returns a vector most likely. `(power(L,x(1)) + power(C,x(2))+power(COV,x(3)))` is 22 by 1, and regardless of what `expected_value` is, I doubt the dimensions change -- so `score` is 22-by-1, when it should (by your problem statement) be 1 by 1.

Comment: i edited the problem to show what is the goal precisely

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is saying exactly what's wrong: your fitness function should return a scalar. Based on your code, I am thinking that you want to use the [root-mean-square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_mean_square) of some quantities as the fitness. To achieve this, simply `sum()` the squared quantities before taking the square root:

```
function score= Fitness_fct(x,L,C,COV,expected_score) 
   %L,C,COV and expected_score are vector of size 22 by 1
   %x is the population (coefficients) that the GA uses

   score=sqrt(sum(power(((power(L,x(1)) + power(C,x(2))+power(COV,x(3)))- 
      expected_value),2))); % note the added sum()
end

 FitnessFunction =@(x) Fitness_fct(x,L ,C,COV, expected_score );
 [x,fval] = ga(FitnessFunction,4);
 % here x will be the optimized coefficients and fval will be the   
   value obtained by the optimized coefficients
```